# How to connect MS SQL database to Ruby

Tags: sql-server, ruby, rubygems, sequel

I am attempting to connect a MS SQL database to my Ruby program in the interest of running read-only queries.  I tried using Sequel, Ruby-DBI and TinyTDS to no avail.

This is my code for connecting with Sequel:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

hostname = 'DB name'
username = 'username here'
password = 'password here'
port = 1433

connection_instance = Sequel.connect(:host => hostname, :user => username, :password => password, :test => true)
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
: LoadError: cannot load such file -- sequel/adapters/ (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)

        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:98:in `load_adapter'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:28:in `adapter_class'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.35.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:56:in `connect'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.35.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:108:in `connect'
        from snippet.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [tinytds](https://rubygems.org/gems/tiny_tds) with:

```
      @db = Sequel.tinytds(
        :host     =>  options['dbserver'], 
        :database=> options['db'],      
        :user       => options['dbuser'],
        :password=> options['dbpwd'],
        #:timeout => options['timeout'], #for long lasting requests
      )
```

In the past I used ado, but with ado I had problems (encoding errors, timeouts...)